# QWidget (from Qt Designer) in centralZone of QMainWindow

Tags: qt-creator, qwidget, qt-designer, qmainwindow

I have a simuWindows.ui (and its .cpp and .h files associated) which is a QWidget.
I have a mainWindows.cpp and mainWindows.h.

What I would like to do is to set my QWidget (simuWindows) as a centralZone of mainWindows.

Here is what I have tried :
mainWindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindows.h"
#include "simuWindows.h"

m_centralZone = new QWidget;
simuWindows mainSimuWindows;
QHBoxLayout mainLayout;
mainLayout.addWidget(&mainSimuWindows);
m_centralZone->setLayout(&mainLayout);
```

However, the widget will not show up and I don't why.

Is my code correct to add my simuWindows.ui widget as centralZone of my QMainWindows ?

EDIT : Here is the correct code (thx to @ekhumoro) :

```
#include "mainwindows.h"
#include "ui_simuWindows.h"

Ui::simuWindows mainSimuWindows;
QWidget *simuWidget = new QWidget;
mainSimuWindows.setuoUi(simuWidget);
setCentralWidget(simuWidget);
m_centralZone->setLayout(&mainLayout);
```

Comment: You need to [set the central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget): `mainSimuWindows->setCentralWidget(m_centralZone)`.

Comment: mainSimuWindows is my QWidget I want to be the centralZone.
My QMainWindow is mainWindows.

Comment: Okay. So: `mainWindows->setCentralWidget(mainSimuWindows)`.

Comment: Thx, you put me on the right way ! :). I've eddited my post with the working code.